# Request header missing even though its passed successfully

Tags: spring-boot

I have built a web application in Spring Boot. This is the code from the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCapabilities(@RequestParam(value = "selectedRRCode", required = false) String selectedRRCode,
        @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorization,
        @RequestHeader(value = "td-api-consumer-key") String apiConsumerKey) {
String capability;
try {
    if () {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //do something
}
return capability;
}
```

The error that I am getting is : ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:146 resolveException - Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Required request header 'td-api-consumer-key' for method parameter type String is not present]

What may be the problem ? I am migrating this app from Spring 5 to springboot 2.7. It works fine in Spring5. Please let me know what I'm missing here. Thanks

Comment: how are you testing this?

Comment: through postman

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the following in spring boot

```
 @RequestHeader(value = "td-api-consumer-key")
```

The default is "requried". you are not providing this header. So, to mitigate
the problem, you can try require="false" first just to prove it.

Comment: but I am providing this value in postman header